# Does 'Call by Reference ' mechanism help in some way in a recursion program?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, recursion, palindrome

I have used references for strings 's' and 'x' because I thought that in function call stack, each call will have its separate copy of strings 's' and 'x' and it will tax program's performance.

So does this actually helps ? ( I am not asking for an alternative solution of Palindrome checking.)

```
bool checkPalindrome(string &s,string &x,int indexToExtract){
    if(indexToExtract < 0){
        if(s == x){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    x = x + s[indexToExtract];
    return checkPalindrome(s,x,indexToExtract - 1);
}

int main(){
    string x = "sassas";
    string y = "";
    cout << checkPalindrome(x,y,x.size() - 1);
    
}
```

Comment: You're right. The only difference between a function call and a recursive call is that you call the function you're within. So yes, it helps. The same as using references in any other function call. You copy the reference, not the object.

Comment: "each call will have its separate copy of strings" - passing strings rarely causes copies fwiw (though I forget the specifics). You should also mark your parameters as `const` too.